# What's meant here by "I have some status in"?

Tags: meaning

In "The Worst Crime in the World" by G. K. Chesterton, Father Brown want to go with his friend, Mr. Granby, who want to go to an old castle to know some information about the inheritance of the father of Captain Musgrave, who is an old sir:

“If Captain Musgrave is really so kind,” said Father Brown gravely. “I may explain that **I have some status in** Mr. Granby’s inquiry, and it would be a great relief to my mind if I could go.”

Does "I have some status in" mean "**I'm interested in**"?

Comment: He has a valid reason for being included in Mr. Granby's enquiry.

Comment: Thank you so much.